# Compile lime-legacy on RPi

Tags: raspberry-pi2, haxe

I am trying to run some code on RPi2 and unfortunately I am forced (thanks to haxeui) to use legacy version of the lime. There is no precompiled version for RPI, so I have to build it on my own. 
Trying to run hxcpp build in on legacy/project ends up with error, that options file is not provided.
Second thing I tried is executing

```
lime rebuild linux -Dlegacy -Drpi -v
```

But it seems, that legacy flag get overridden with the rpi as no legacy file is created.

I am using git version of lime/openfl/haxe/hxcpp on latest rasbpian which I compiled thanks to the http://www.gepatto.nl/get-piratepig-running-on-a-raspberry-pi-2-with-raspbian-jessie/ tutorial.

How can I run build with both legacy and rpi flags?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Via OpenFL forum](http://community.openfl.org/t/solved-compiling-lime-legacy-on-rpi2/7816/3), current dev branches does no longer support legacy, yo you need to switch to `openfl3` branch for openfl and `master` branch for lime.